# Update Business Account or Person account?

Tags: person-accounts

I just have a quick question with regards to creating business accounts in the CRM – if we have a list of agents/builders that we want to add, and eventually send out eDM’s to etc. – do they go in as business accounts or as person accounts, because the business account doesn’t have an email field available.

Or do I need to create the business account, and then attached a contact card to each one? Which seems to be an awfully long process if it is going to a generic ‘admin@email’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your data model and how it all ties back to your overall solution. Either way it's not right or wrong, again depending on your use case.

If an account is going to have multiple contacts for X reasons, then it should be a business account and each of the contacts would be related contacts to that account. Keep in mind that you can flag each contact (by creating additional fields on the contact object) as Primary etc. Based on that you can easily then find which contact you need to use in a certain business process. Also having this structure you can implement logic that will copy the desired contact's email address onto the account record (with a workflow, trigger etc.) so that you don't have to deal with the contacts at all and have the email address of the primary contact always available on the account level. That's just an example but you can see where I'm going with this.

The other option - having a person account means the account is a business account and a contact at the same time - it will not have multiple contacts related to itself. The person account is basically a mixed object of both Account and Contact and you have the fields from both objects available on each record.

Hope this makes things more clear. Not knowing your end-to-end solution, I can't tell if one or other will fit in better.